# Greek letters aren't displayed in my web browser's page

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse

I 've written the following code snippet in **Eclipse html form** which include headings and titles in **greek characters**.
My problem is that these characters can't be correctly displayed in my web browser's page although I've set **UTF-8 Encoding**. Instead, they are displayed like question symbols (????).

My code snippet:

```js
var product = $scope.product = [];               // Custom JavaScript creates a JavaScript Object and binds it to the current AngularJS $scope of the form as a variable named "product".                                                                       
  $scope.addProduct = function () {             // We make a function named "addProduct".
   var product = {};                // We add a new "product" to the Array.
   product.Category = $scope.Category;
   product.Description = $scope.Description;
   if (!!$scope.camForm.fields[0].element[0].files[0]) {
    product.Details = $scope.camForm.fields[0].element[0].files[0].name;  // We check whether a file is uploaded.
   } else {
     return;                 // If no file is uploaded, it returns "undefined".
   }
   product.Price = $scope.Price;
   $scope.product.push(product);             // We use the value of the "product" input field to add a new "product" to the Array.
   $scope.Category = "";               // We clear the TextBox "���������".
   $scope.Description = "";              // We clear the TextBox "���������".
   $scope.Details = "";               // We clear the TextBox "������������".
   $scope.Price = "";                // We clear the TextBox "����".
  };
  $scope.removeProduct = function (index) {           // We make a function named "removeProduct".      
   var category = $scope.product[index].Category;         // We find product's Category using "index" from the Array and binds it to the current AngularJS $scope of the form as a variable named "category".
   $scope.product.splice(index, 1);            // We use an index to remove a "product" from the Array.
  }
  $scope.isAddFormValid = function () {            // We make a function named "isAddFormValid".
   return ($scope.Category &&
     $scope.Description &&
     $scope.camForm.fields[0].element[0].files[0] &&
     $scope.Price) ? true : false;           // If all of the 4 parameters of variable "product" are added, the value will be "true", otherwise the value will be "false".
  }
  camForm.on('form-loaded', function() {            // We hook into the lifecycle of Camunda SDK JS Form.
   camForm.variableManager.createVariable ({          // We "create" (declare) a new process variable  
     name:'product',               // named 'product' and
     type:'json',               // provide as type information 'json' used for serialization.
     value:product
   });
  });
  camForm.on('submit', function(evt) {            // We hook into the lifecycle of Camunda SDK JS Form.
   if (product.length<1) {               // If no "product" is added,
    evt.submitPrevented = true;             // an event handler prevents the form from being submitted by setting the property "submitPrevented" to 'true'.
   }
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>                                
  <meta charset="UTF-8">                           
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">               
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">                   
  <title>Document</title>                           
 </head>
 <body>
  <form role="form" name="insertForm" accept-charset="utf-8">
   <h2><b>����� ���������</b></h2>                        <!-- We set the heading of the HTML Table. -->
   <div>             
    <table style="width:100%;">                        
     <thead>                            <!-- We group the header content in the HTML Table. -->
      <tr>                           <!-- The header content of the HTML Table is not repeated. -->                           
       <th style="width:140px;">���������</th>
       <th style="width:305px;">���������</th>
       <th style="width:250px;">������������</th>
       <th style="width:75px;" >���� (�)</th>
       <th></th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody ng-repeat="x in product track by $index">                 <!-- The HTML Table is populated from the JSON Array "product", using a "ng-repeat" directive which is assigned to each row of the Table in order to repeat all the objects of the Array. -->
      <tr>                           <!-- Each row of the HTML Table consists of 4 HTML Input Form fields and 1 button. -->             
       <td><input style="width:140px;" type="text" value="{{x.Category}}" /></td>      
       <td><input style="width:305px;" type="text" value="{{x.Description}}" /></td>
       <td><input style="width:250px;" type="text" value="{{x.Details}}" /></td> 
       <td><input style="width:75px;"  type="number" value="{{x.Price}}" /></td>
       <td><input type="button" ng-click="removeProduct($index)" value="Remove" /></td>       <!-- The "ng-click" directive is assigned to the "Remove" button and calls the function named "removeProduct" with the current "$index" when this button is clicked. -->
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
   <hr>                              <!-- We separate the HTML content. -->
   <div>
    <h2><b>���������� ��� ������</b></h2>                      <!-- We set the heading of the HTML Form. -->
    <div class="row">                          <!-- We set the "1st row" of the HTML Form. --> 
     <div class="col-md-6">                        <!-- We use "md" for "medium" screen devices of width equal to or greater than 992px and "6" for adding 6 columns. -->               
      <div class="form-group">                      <!-- We use "form-group" for optimum spacing. -->
       <label class="control-label" for="category">���������</label>
       <div class="controls">
        <input style="width:140px;" id="category" type="text" ng-model="Category" />       <!-- The "ng-model" directive binds the value of the "���������" input field to the created variable "Category" in AngularJS. -->
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">                        
      <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label" for="Description">���������</label>
       <div class="controls">
        <input style="width:305px;" id="Description" type="text" ng-model="Description" />      <!-- The "ng-model" directive binds the value of the "���������" input field to the created variable "Description" in AngularJS. --> 
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">                          <!-- We set the "2nd row" of the HTML Form. -->
     <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label" for="Details">������������</label>
       <div class="controls">
        <input style="width:250px;"
               id="Details"
               type="file"
               cam-variable-name="Details"
                  cam-variable-type="File"
                  cam-max-filesize="10000000" ng-model="Details" />            <!-- The "ng-model" directive binds the value of the "������������" input field to the created variable "Details" in AngularJS. -->
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label" for="price">���� (�)</label>
       <div class="controls">
        <input style="width:75px;" id="price" type="number" ng-model="Price" />         <!-- The "ng-model" directive binds the value of the "���� (�)" input field to the created variable "Price" in AngularJS. -->
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">                          <!-- We set the "3rd row" of the HTML Form. -->
     <div class="col-md-4">                        <!-- We use "md" for medium screen devices of width equal to or greater than 992px and "4" for adding 4 columns. -->
      <div class="controls">
       <input type="button" ng-click="addProduct()" ng-show="isAddFormValid()" value="Add" />      <!-- The "ng-show" directive shows the input element ("Add" button) only if the "isAddFormValid()" expression (function) returns "true". The "ng-click" directive is assigned to the "Add" button and calls the function named "addProduct()" when this button is clicked. -->
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <script src="insert-products-and-specifications.js" charset="utf-8" cam-script type="text/form-script"></script>   <!-- We call the external script file ("insert-products-and-specifications.js"). -->
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have any idea on this please?
Thanks,
Steve

Comment: You need to use UTF8.

Comment: Are you using any special fonts?

Comment: works on JS fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/93scwzca/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <form role="form" name="startForm" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <h2>Ώρα για προμήθειες</h2>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Many thanks, it really solves my issue. But what if in case I've written both html and javascript? I tried to do exactly the same in my above edited code snippet without any success.

Comment: Glad to help you. To use utf-8 in javascript try to add <script src="jsfile.js" charset="utf-8"></script>in your script call. 
But basically I see that you had mixed CSS and HTML code, maybe it's would be great for you to get an eye on the documentation and the functionment of  the HTML.

Comment: Hi again. I 've just edited my above code snippet here (by creating an external js file) and I did exactly what you mentioned (by adding the "charset" attribute in my script call) but my encoding issue still exists when it comes to javascript. May I do sth wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="el">
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <form role="form" name="startForm" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <h2>Ώρα για προμήθειες</h2>
        </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like also to know how could I apply this in case I 've included both html and javascript in my code. I 've edited my initial code snippet here.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my issue.
I didn't modify something in my code.
The solution was to change some **general settings** in my eclipse editor.
For anyone who may face the same **encoding issue in eclipse**, I wrote the following steps:

check and maybe change the following preferences in your eclipse.

The encoding of the text editor should be UTF-8.
– General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Spelling -> Encoding -> Default UTF-8
The encoding for the HTML files should be UTF-8. For that, you can configure to use the workspace encoding.
– Web -> HTML-Files -> Use workspace encoding
The encoding of your workspace should be UTF-8.
– General -> Workspace -> Text file encoding -> Other -> UTF-8
You should also check the encoding of your resource. For that, please click with the right mouse button on your eclipse project and choose Properties. In the new opened window, click on Resource and check the value of the Text file encoding